# How can I submit only form elements in Vue[2].js?

Tags: forms, vue.js, form-submit, element-ui

I have a form page and I use it for both create and update

My form fields are like this;

```
myForm: {
  name: (...)
  email: (...)
  password: (...)
}
```

I can successfully submit a request.

When we come to the update process, I get the data in this way (this.myForm = response.data)

When I send an update request I just want the form fields to go but it goes like this

```
myForm: {
  name: (...)
  email: (...)
  password: (...)
  createdAt: (...)
  updatedAt: (...)
  _id: (...)
}
```

*I don't want to send* **createdAt, updatedAt, _id** *fields*

How can I submit only form fields in Vue.js or Element-ui? (I am using element-ui btw)

Is there something like **this.$refs.myForm.fields** or **this.$refs.myForm.values** I couldn't find it

My code: [Code picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d01Ob.png)

```
<template>
  <div class="app-container">
    <el-form ref="myForm" label-position="top" :model="myForm">
      <el-form-item>
        <label>Name</label>
        <el-input v-model="myForm.name" />
      </el-form-item>
      <el-form-item>
        <label>Email</label>
        <el-input v-model="myForm.email" />
      </el-form-item>
      <el-form-item>
        <label>Password</label>
        <el-input v-model="myForm.password" />
      </el-form-item>
      <el-button type="primary" @click="submitForm('myForm')">Kaydet</el-button>
    </el-form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'UserForm',
  data() {
    return {
      myForm: {
        name: '',
        email: '',
        password: ''
      }
    }
  },
  created() {
    if (this.$route.params.id) {
      this.getFormData(this.$route.params.id)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    submitForm() {
      if (!this.$route.params.id) {
        this.$store.dispatch('user/create', this.myForm)
      } else {
        this.$store.dispatch('user/update/', this.myForm)
      }
    },
    getFormData(id) {
      this.$store.dispatch('user/get', id).then((response) => {
        this.myForm = response.data
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Define a computed property based on `response.data` and assign that to `myForm`. The code depends on the specific structure of the response, but the general idea would be `let x = {}; Object.entries( response.data ).forEach ( a_entry => { if ( /* condition based on a_entry[0], eg. <some set>.has(a_entry[0]) */ ) { x[a_entry[0]] = a_entry[1]; } } );`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of posting the entire 'this.myForm', just specify the fields you want to post in a new object.

```
submitForm() {
  if (!this.$route.params.id) {
    this.$store.dispatch('user/create', this.myForm)
  } else {
    this.$store.dispatch('user/update/', {
      name: this.myForm.name,
      email: this.myForm.email,
      password: this.myForm.password
    })
  }
}
```

UPDATE: Following comments from OP, if you're expecting more that 'name', 'email', and 'password', you can just delete the properties you don't want to send.

```
 submitForm() {
  if (!this.$route.params.id) {
    this.$store.dispatch('user/create', this.myForm)
  } else {
    delete this.myForm.createdAt,
    delete this.myForm.updatedAt,
    delete this.myForm._id
    this.$store.dispatch('user/update/', this.myForm)
  }
}
```

Comment: True but not useful.
I have shown 3 fields here. I actually have 20 fields.
There must be a better method

Comment: There's not going to be a function that does this for you - the 'createdAt' and 'updatedAt' are fields that are being returned by your API. So you either a) have to stop the API returning them, or b) remove them from the object before you post it back. If it's just those three properties you don't want to send, I'll update my answer now showing how to delete them.